How to write a script for a set of parallel dependent tasks job on slurm?
I am trying to use slurm to submit a job in which I want to do multiple runs of a set of (task1,task2); task2 needs some results of task1.
I want to submit only one job that runs multiple iterations of (task1,task2) in parallel and saves the order of completion for task1 and task2.
I know how to do it with two different slurm jobs using dependency but I don't want to sbatch two bash files instead, I want to do it only with a single sbatch, is it possible?
